# Laravel PHP If/Else in Blade Doesn't Work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

Laravel PHP fans, Any idea why this renders both the actual partial view and the No Data Found as well? And interestingly, it renders No Data Found first. If I do a dump and die in the if condition, I get that dd. If I put it in the else condition, I get it there. It must  be that the page starts rendering before the data for regionLevel actually comes back. Then when it does it dutifully prints it out. Is there any way around this weirdness?

```
@if(isset($regionLevel) && count($regionLevel) > 0)
    <div class="size-wrapper">
        @include('manager/reports/order-data/sections/partials/region-partial')
    </div>
@else
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-left m-t-5 m-b-5 m-l-10">No data found.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: How do you get your ``$regionLevel``? Through JS, controller, anywhere else? Is your if statement wrapped inside a foreach? 
From what we have, there doesn't seem to have any problem in your code, it must be from the data or code outside

Comment: @Lyzvaleska that may be it. I get it from the controller.